# Does software distributed for Ubuntu work for Ubuntu flavors?

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu

I am planning on dual booting a windows 11 laptop with an AMD Ryzen 5 processor, 8 GB RAM, and 512 GB SSD with Lubuntu. I planned on using Lubuntu because it is lightweight, and I wanted to use a distribution that is well-supported (I assume this since Lubuntu is an official flavor of Ubuntu). However, if for example I wanted to install MATLAB on this laptop, the [MATLAB Linux System Requirements](https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/matlab-linux.html) list several distributions, including

> ```
> Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
> Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
> Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
> ```

but will software distributed for Ubuntu work with Lubuntu? I am sure this is very much a noob question, but this is my first time looking into dual-booting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but will software distributed for Ubuntu work with Lubuntu?

Yes they do.

Lubuntu is just the same Ubuntu underneawith a different user interface and a different choice of default programs which make it lighter.

Comment: Unless the program in question depends on the features provided by a particular  DE. Then it may have a problem.

Comment: @raj In which case it should depend on that DE directly, not on the flavor of Ubuntu it’s running on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and even anything based on Ubuntu such as Linux Mint, "deb" (debian) packages install and work with no problems.

Dual booting however, microsuck are making more and more sure that's not an option anymore. Their forced "updates" now overwrite the bootloader with their windows-only one, making it a pain in the ass to "rescue boot" into Linux from USB/external drive and rewrite the bootloader each time. Also i wouldn't be surprised if further windows "updates" in the future will completely nuke your Linux partition(s) altogether - if they don't do that already.